# How would I unnest multiple folders in Windows programatically?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, batch-rename, files-folders

So, I have a folder structure with some downloads that goes like this (I manually edited it a bit because it contains some sensitive data, which is not relevant to the question. The extensions are also not common, nor relevant):

```
C:.
│   [FILENAME].[ext]
│   
├───Example 1
│   └───Example 1
│       └───Example 1
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   
│           └───Folder.[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │   
│               ├───test1
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       
│               ├───test10
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       
│               ├───test11
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       
│               ├───test12
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│               │       
│               ├───test2
│                       [FILENAME].[ext]
│                       [FILENAME].[ext]
│                       
│                       
├───Example 2
│   └───Example 2
│       └───Example 2
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   
│           ├───Folder.[ext]
│           │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │       [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │       
│           └───Setup
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   
├───Example 3
│   └───Example 3
│       └───Example 3
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   
│           └───Folder.[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   
├───Example 4
│   └───Example 4
│       └───Example 4
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│           │   
│           └───Folder.[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]
│                   [FILENAME].[ext]

                             .
                             .
                             .
```

As you can see, there are a lot of unnecessary folders in-between before the actual files.

Is it possible to use batch to programmatically remove the "intermediate folders"? Basically, I want to remove any folders that contain only folders and bring the sub-contents up one level. How would it be done (preferably with only built-in Windows tools)?

On this small excerpt, simply removing the first two parent "Example #" folders would solve for all, but the nesting depth occasionally varies up or down. If a folder contains only a single folder, it's a "middle man" that I want to remove, if there are actual files (or more than one folder, which means it's actual organization), than it should remain there.

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm trying to achieve something like this, removing the triplicated (but sometimes other depths) nesting:

```
C:.
├───Example 1
│    │   [FILENAME].[ext]
│    │   [FILENAME].[ext]
       .
       .
       .
```

Comment: To be clear, specify in the post exactly the final folder structure that you want. What have you already researched or tried?

Comment: Why not to use `tree /f` for illustrate your folder tree, and, size is not useful information on this task

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe OMG, I just have been searching for a command like this for hours, thank you, I'll soon improve my question.

I'm a bit worried about sensitive file names, so right now I'm reworking a sample from the full `tree /f` output.

Comment: Are the nested foldernames actually identical? That makes things trickier...

Comment: Yes, they are. I used a single RegEx per Example # to produce the excerpt above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PowerShell**, a simple recursive function could find the first subfolder that contains files. The content of that folder can then be moved to its top-level container. afer that, empty folders can be deleted. Just edit `$Top` to reflect the path to your folder:

```
$Top = 'c:\TopFolder'
Function Get-NonEmptyPath ($FPath) {
   If ( -not (gci -LiteralPath $FPath -file) ) {
      $Return = Get-NonEmptyPath ( gci -LiteralPath $FPath -Directory  ).FullName
   } Else { $Return = $FPath }
   $Return
}

Filter Get-LiteralPath { $_ | Select  @{ N='LiteralPath'; E={ $_.FullName }}}

( Get-ChildItem $Top -Directory ).FullName  | ForEach{
   If (( $Buried = Get-NonEmptyPath $_ ) -ne $null ) {
      gci -LiteralPath $Buried | Get-LiteralPath | Move-Item -Destination $_
      For ( $Empty = $Buried ; $Empty -ne $_ ; ( $Empty = Split-Path -LiteralPath $Empty )) {
         Remove-Item -LiteralPath $Empty
      }
   }
}
```

After editing `$Top`, the entire block can be copied & psted into a **PowerShell** console window.

[gci/Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

[ForEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-5.1)

[About For](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-5.1)

[Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Move-Item?view=powershell-5.1)

[Split-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Split-Path?view=powershell-5.1)

[Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Can this be run from anywhere or do I have to change my working directory?

Comment: I believe `Get-NonEmptyPath` has a mistake, as I'm getting a "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" error (multiple times).

Some of my folder names have spaces in it. Could this be the cause?

Comment: It prints a lot of errors, but it does work, thank you!

Comment: Did any of the paths contain braqkets or parentheses or other odd charactes?

Comment: Yes, I can see all of these in my old tree.txt: `' ! . - ( )`. Let me put it like this: despite the odd extensions I have, all of these folders are *titles*. Nevertheless, the new tree was generated perfectly!

Comment: Then those could likely be eliminated by using the `-LiteralPath` parameter in lieu of `-Path` (explicit or positional) where possible.

Comment: Ah, very nice. I can't test it, as I don't have the original tree anymore, but could you add this information to the answer? I intend to leave it bookmarked.

Comment: Fully modified to deal with special characters.

Comment: I believe you left behind an extra occurrence of `$Target` in line 13, but removed the section that specified it. The current version doesn't work, so I used the one from Edit 3 to deal with another tree!

Comment: You need to edit you question and show me error messaged!!!! And post better sample data --- not so simplified as to be useless!!!!

Comment: I don't always do that because my Windows is not in English, so error messages wouldn't be readable without extra editing, I only submitted such simple feedback because I judged by your edit history that you intended to remove all occurrences of `$Target`. I'll be soon editing my original question.

Comment: Target was changed to $_. But having issues with `-notlike`...`'C:\Users\Keith\Sandbox\TestRoot\nested (1)[2]' -notlike 'C:\Users\Keith\Sandbox\TestRoot\nested (1)[2]'` is returning `True`?!?!?

Comment: Even an error messge is a foreogn languge would give me a clue as to which cmdlet is throwing an error --- which is more that "doesn't work" does!

Comment: Your last edit made it flawless, no errors and produces the desired output, thank you. Do you still want me to run the old version through my tree?

Comment: I see no reason to do so. I'm curious about the behavior of `-notLIke`, but posted in MS TechNet forums for clarification.